# i want to change dashboard background color to Black in kibana 7.0.1 version

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat, heartbeat

I am using the Kibana 7.0.1 and I want to change the background color of the complete dashboard to black color, but I cannot find this option on UI. Is there any way to do this ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[What you need to do](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.0/release-highlights-7.0.0.html#_kibana_dark_theme):

1. Go to "Management > Advanced settings"
2. Flip the dark mode switch
3. Reload the page

Comment: Thank you! i want to change the theme color to black... i am not getting that option in kibana 7.0.1 version...

Comment: That option is available since 7.0.0

Comment: Yeah i got it!.... thank you... in kibana visualisation ex: graph,chart and all will look like a basic... is there any other option of getting graphically good and to understand easily?... user friendly type... i am new to this technology

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... did the dark mode work?